# C# winforms draw to bitmap invalid parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have made an application, and i need the function drawbitmap to print my panel. When i push the button (btnUpdate) 12 times or more I get a parameter exception(invalid parameter)on this rule: `panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));`

```
private void preview()
        {
            Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
            panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            preview();
        }
```

Can someone help me please?

I can't use the `bmp1.Dispose();` function... I get an exeption in the Program.cs file in this line: `Application.Run(new Form1());`

Comment: does it always happen after twelfth click or just because you are clicking too fast.

I managed to get your exception and the stack trace says it occurs in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp
Is this the case?

Comment: Just accept Jim's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed by doing this:

```
private void preview()
{

    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
    Image img = pictureBox2.Image;
    pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
    if (img != null) img.Dispose(); // the first time it'll be null

}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    preview();
    System.GC.Collect();
    System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: Your `preview` method is exactly what I recommended. Are you sure that the `GC.Collect` and `WaitForPendingFinalizers` are required? That would be ... surprising.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the RAM Usage will be increased, and the application is using 1.5 Gigabites of RAM.. And this is a method I will call several times in the runtime.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a case of not disposing the bitmaps when you're done with them. Try this:

```
panel1.DrawToBitmap(...);

// get old image 
Bitmap oldBitmap = pictureBox2.Image as Bitmap;

// set the new image
pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;

// now dispose the old image
if (oldBitmap != null)
{
    oldBitmap.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: BTW you need to cast `pictureBox2.Image`

Comment: This is what i've replaced: panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508)); but it doesn't work... I dont get it, and I have placed this global Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480,3508);

Comment: @FerryJongmans: Edit your question and show us the *exact* error message you get, including the inner exception. Also, show us the *exact* code that that you're using now. "It doesn't work" is not very descriptive and is unlikely to elicit a useful response.

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null 
this is what i get

Answer (score 1):

You have a great big Memory leak there, watch your memory as you click the button 12 clicks and your up to 1GB,

try declaring you Bitmap as a varable and Dispose it before re assigning.

```
    private Bitmap bmp1;
    private void preview()
    {
        if (bmp1 != null)
        {
            bmp1.Dispose();
        }
        bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
        pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
    }
```

Or just clear the PictureBox befor assigning a new Bitmap

```
    private void preview()
    {
        if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image.Dispose();
        }
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
        pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
    }
```

Comment: With this solutions, I get a not enough memory exception

Comment: Which one, I tested both and there was no memory leak.

Comment: I get an out of memory exception, Not enough memory. at the second one and at the first one i get invalid parameter...