# How to save save high frame rate camera images with live preview

Tags: c#, image, winforms, camera, frame-rate

I have two high speed USB3 cameras (Ximea) and want to code an application for image recording. Framerates are up to 500fps at VGA resolution but I also want to use the 2Mpx resolution at 170fps.
Their .Net SDK tells me that I should simply "get" the images in a loop. 
My problem is that I have no idea how to get the images and save them while still showing a live preview. Everytime I add some code to actually update the picturebox the frame rate drops drastically.

At the moment I utilize a recording function that is called with

```
Task.Run(() => Record());
```

and inside the Record() I have a loop getting the bitmaps

```
while(record == true)
{
    Camera.GetImage(out myImage, timeout); //From Ximea .Net SDK
    Info = Camera.GetLastImageParams();
    Timestamp = Info.GetTimeStamp();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => SaveImage(myImage, filepath, Timestamp));
}
```

with the SaveImage being

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap myImage, string filepath, double Timestamp)
{
    try
    {
        lock(myImage)
        {
             myImage.Save(filepath + Timestamp.ToString("0.00000") + ".tif");
        }
    }
    catch{}
}
```

How can I show a live preview while recording and how can I make the entire code more stable (at the moment there are some dropped frames because of "object already in use"-errors or "generic error in GDI+" at the Image.Save() call, that I skip with the try/catch statement)?

Comment: You know saving to hard drive is not the best idea. 2 mpx is roughly 2.5 mb files. You want 170 image per seconds so want to write 425 mb per second to your harddisk and still be able to load it into a picturebox. If you have an SSD you might be short in write speed. Some barely do 300 mb  per seconds. You want a buffer instead. Ram is much faster to read and write.

Comment: @Franck in my case I am saving to either SSD or Ram Disk - so write speeds should be fast enough. Also the images are monochrome so not that big in size - 2Mpx tifs are 700KB with this camera.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can tell the Ximea API how many image buffers you want in the incoming queue... use XI_PRM_BUFFER_POLICY and XI_PRM_BUFFERS_QUEUE_SIZE appropriately to make that queue length somewhat long.
Then, have a thread that, when activated, copies an image out of a XI_IMG struct into your own buffer. Activate that thread every n frames (based on the size of the Ximea image buffer queue size)... but don't do any memory copies in the loop that actually calls xiGetImage. You should probably block in your thread to avoid tearing (because the Ximea code could get back around to using the same buffer again if you're not fast enough at copying the data out)... but you could then dynamically adjust the number of buffers so you can finish your copy within the time you have. Also, you may consider copying the image data to ANOTHER buffer if you're doing something that takes a long time...

pseudo-code (sorry, it's C-ish):

```
// sync objects and a global image buffer pointer
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
void *buf;
HANDLE ev;

int CopyImageThreadProc(...)
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (WaitOnSingleObject(ev) == WAIT_OBJ_0)
    {
      EnterCriticalSection(cs);
      // copy the image data at buf where ever you want
      LeaveCriticalSection(cs);
    }
  }
}

int main(...)
{
  // set up ximea api with appropriate buffering

  // create event and critsec, start thread

  while (!done)
  {
    XI_IMG img;
    xiGetImage(dev, 10, &img);

    // every 15 frames, tell your thread to go...
    // if you find that the critsec is causing a hiccup, you can adjust this
    // but remember to adjust the queue length, too
    // if you change this to TRY entercriticalsection, you can determine that
    if ((img.acq_nframe % 15) == 0)
    {
      EnterCriticalSection(cs);
      buf = img.bp;
      SetEvent(ev);
      LeaveCriticalSection(cs);
    }
  }

  // clean up
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each captured frame to a queue, then have a worker thread that takes those images, one at a time, and saves them. Trying to write multiple images to disk at the same time will most likely be slower. Also, always `Dispose` of any `GDI` objects or you will run into trouble really fast. I would think not doing that is what is giving you the exceptions.

As for showing the images, make sure you are not trying to display every image. Your monitor most likely runs at 60 Hz, so anything faster than that will be a waste. I also suspect that (with the performance of GDI), you won't necessarily be able to achieve even that. So I suggest you have a second queue with images to display, and if you see that queue getting too large, your program will need to slow down a bit and not push as many frames to the queue.

Edit: And of course, as @Franck mentions, if your disk can't keep up, your queue/buffer will fill up quickly. Compressing the images might help, assuming they have suitable content for compression and that your processor can keep up.

Edit: What you need is a producer-consumer pattern. There are many ways of doing this, but one might be something like:

```
// blocking collection
private BlockingCollection<Bitmap> m_Queue = ...

// camera thread
while( run )
{
    var bitmap = GrabFrame();
    m_Queue.Add( bitmap );
}

// worker thread
try
{        
    while( true )
    {
        // Take() will block if the queue is empty
        var bitmap = m_Queue.Take();
        bitmap.Save( ... );
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
catch( InvalidOperationException )
{
     // you'll end up here if you call `m_Queue.CompleteAdding()`
     // (after the queue has been emptied, of course)
}
```

As for displaying the images, you could probably use something similar, with the addition of having some code that determines if it's time to push a new image or not.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this - some Pseudo Code would be really appreciated. The GDI error usually comes from a Timestamp that is already saved - no idea how that is even possible with a Queue but apparently sometimes an image with the same Timestamp already exists.

Comment: Chris is right about refresh rate, 170 fps is useless if you screen is not at least 170hz, which i think after 120hz it jump to 300hz. And spending so much money on such monitor to display a very small video is a strange choice.

Comment: @Franck I obviously do not want to show 170fps on screen - I just need maybe 30 fps to see whats going on and if the object is still in focus.
Thanks Chris - will try it out.

Comment: @Chris I tried your code and at first I thought it would work. After testing it by recording a stopwatch however I discovered, that the images are apparently not correctly saved to the Collection. I made it so that the Worker starts only after the recording is finished (RAM is not an issue on my machine) and the saved images are from after the recording has finished. Somehow new images seem to overwrite the existing ones in the collection. Doing m_Queue.Add(new Bitmap(bitmap)) helps but lowers the framerate drastically. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @DanielM That does seem strange. If you use the default parameter-less constructor of `BlockingCollection` it'll internally use a `ConcurrentQueue` (FIFO) and no maximum capacity. Try writing a wrapper class for the bitmap with some additional data, like an image# integer, and have a look if all the images come through.

Comment: @Chris it looks like the camera getImage() does just simply update the pixel data in memory - so the object stays the same but the actual image information changes (just like a pointer) - that is why a full copy with new Bitmap() works (but is too slow). Any idea how to circumvent this? I am thinking of writing the byte arrays into a memory stream and then read the images from there but again have to read up on how this is done without some Pseudo code.

Comment: @DanielM Ah, so the camera driver reuses the bitmap? Very uncool. What does their docs say? If I were you I'd look to see if there's any alternative way of getting the images, preferably one that doesn't involve System.Drawing at all. If not, use `Bitmap.LockBits` and copy the data to a `byte[]`. Just remember to do this on the camera thread!

Comment: the file get written over because of your naming convention. Never use timestamps for fast algorithm. If you run a sample loop and try getting `DateTime.Ticks` as an example you will see you will get duplicates as well. Use a manual index such as long or int64

Comment: @Franck no they actually do get written over. When using the BlockCollection and starting a recording of a stopwatch from let's say 0 to 1sec and only start saving them to disk afterwards, the actual saved images will show seconds 3,4,5,6 of the stopwatch for example.

Comment: @Chris There is in fact an alternative approach from the manufacturer: getting the image as a byte array with raw pixel data instead of a bitmap object.
By using [SharpAvi](https://sharpavi.codeplex.com/) I am now able to give the byte array to the aviwriter (after appending the image header) and apparently it is able to deal with frame rates of 500fps without a problem.
But to guarantee constant frame rates I can not update the picturebox of my application (so no live view) - any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel how about a secondary process that will get from the list of images the latest, show it in the picturebox then query another one once displayed, because if you store images too fast and try to query each time the control doesn't have the time to show it that you are already requesting a new display. Like that you might show image #1 then 1, then 45 ... ok it's not super stable framerate bu you might get nice result too. Other option is Not live but close. buffer yourself for 5 second delay and then a time that change the picture 30 times per seconds jumping 17 images each time

Comment: @DanielM For each image you get from the camera, check if some amount of time has passed since you displayed an image last, and if so, push it to a second `BlockingCollection` or similar that is monitored by the UI thread. Store the time. Also check the size of the collection, if too many frames start to queue up (your UI can't keep up), increase the interval a bit.

Comment: @Chris tested your idea and it works - thank you so much.
I am using a BlockingCollection with size 1 now, so only when the other task has updated the UI and used the image a new one will be put in. Also thanks to this [Stackoverflow Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946381/c-sharp-winforms-draw-to-bitmap-invalid-parameter) I noticed that I had to dispose of the old Image everytime I update with a new one.

Comment: @DanielM Nice! Make sure you check the `BlockingCollection` before you add an image, so you don't inadvertently block (causing dropped frames). It might actually be enough to use a `ConcurrentCollection` instead, since you don't really need the blocking in that case.